# Post int directly to web api without model class

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am new to C#. I tried to create a post service with using int. All get and post service are working fine.

But when I pass parameter to post service, it's always null. But after creating a class it works fine. Can we pass direct int to service or we must have to create a model class for it?

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserByID(int id)
    {
        var user = userList.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (user== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(user);
    }
```

but it always send 0 .  but when i create a class and add that int as attribute it works fine.

**Working code**

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserByID(data id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok();
    }

   public class data
   {
       [Required]
       public int id { get; set; }
   }
```

**Edit**

> are my header accurate?

[image]

Comment: `Content-Type` is set correctly, I'd remove `Accept-Charset` and `User-Agent` as they are not needed to solve this particular problem. More important is what you're sending in the request body, are you sending an object containing the id in a key/value pair `{ "id": "1" }` or just the id e.g. `1` (this is what you should be sending) - Maybe post what you're sending on the **Body** tab of your screenshot above.

Comment: I have tried both but all primitive data type i get their is null . I tried changing my id to string and cast their to int. put string also got null their.

Comment: I don't see how `id` can be `null`, it's an `int` which is a value type which if not set explicitly will take on its default value of `0` at least, surely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to add `[FromBody]` to the parameter:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserByID([FromBody]int id)
{
    var user = userList.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (user== null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(user);
}
```

According to the docs: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value    from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from 
>     a string.
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message      body, using a media-type formatter.

It goes on to say: [Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

> To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter

**UPDATES - to get `[HttpPost]` working**...

As @Shahbaz suggested below, make sure that you've got the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`, otherwise you will get error message saying:

> The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.

Also, make sure you're posting **just the `id`** in the **Request Body** e.g. `1`, as opposed to posting the id wrapped in a JSON object as a key/value pair `{ "id": "1" }`.

**FINALLY - consider using `[HttpGet]` instead**...

It's worth pointing out, because you are now just sending a single `int` to *get* a single record, even if you can get this working using `[HttpPost]`, it's still probably best to change it to `[HttpGet]` which is semantically correct - you are *getting a user* record, and don't actually need to post anything at all. So something like this might be better:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("api/users/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserByID(int id)
{
    var user = userList.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (user== null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(user);
}
```

Then put your `id` in the request URL, something like:

```
https://yourdomain/api/users/1
```

The above example makes use of [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) which can help  you create your own custom URLs to target your own API Action Methods.

Comment: I was writing the same answer :-)

Comment: I would also suggest to set Content-Type as application/json in the request as web api does not supports text/plain by default.

Comment: I also tried with it. and I am testing it with postman what header should i set in order to test that service. May be the headers are wrong

Comment: get service is working correctly I am just learning. I think we can't send primitive data types to web api . Am I correct ??

Comment: Yeah sure, it's good to play with these things and see what rules they follow. You definitely can post an `int` to WebApi using `[HttpPost]` and pick it up using `[FromBody]` though. You'll see many examples where this is used for deleting a record for example - when only the id of the record is needed to complete the request.

Comment: Problem Solved : first I remove Accept-charSet and UserAgent from header and instead of sending data in form raw I added it using param like ?id=1
it's working fine

Comment: "as opposed to posting the id wrapped in a JSON object as a key/value pair". This is what made all the difference, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Send Data to Web Api by a Jquery Like Below :

```
function PostSth(fid){
  $.ajax({  
    url: apiBaseUrl + 'api/Controller/ActionMethod',  
    type: 'Post',  
    data:`'`+fid+`'`,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {         
        alert(data);

    },  
    error: function () {  
        alert('Error');  
    }  
 });
}
```

Don't Forget

> ```
> data:`'`+fid+`'`,
> ```

above.

and do in the Code Behind Part :

```
public string ActionMethod([FromBody]int fid)
{
     string result = string.Empty;
     //TODO: Your Code

    return result;
}
```